# Mean value of square signal between 0 and 15 V in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, integrator, square

I would like to get a signal that is the mean value of a square signal going from 0 to 15 V using an integrator op-amp. Here is what I'm getting so far (the op-amp I have put is the UniversalOpAmp2):

[image]

For now I can only get an output voltage close to zero, here is a zoom showing that it oscillates very close to zero:

[image]

These things are really new to me so I'm probably missing some crucial points, maybe you could enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *maybe you could enlighten me?*

The integrator circuit you have used also inverts the output. This means that the output would need to be negative for a positive input. This cannot happen with your circuit because the op-amp's negative supply is 0 volts.

> *I would like to get a signal that is the mean value of a square signal
> going from 0V to 15V using an integrator op amp*

An integrator will not produce a mean value. If you want a mean value use a low-pass filter.

> *it oscillates very close to zero*

That is just the input signal passing through the 10 k resistor and integrator capacitor forming a potential divider with the op-amps output impedance hence, you see a waveform that is very close to 0 volts and small in amplitude.

Comment: This explains why I had negative value when I powered it with -15 and 15V :) And so there would be a way to get something close to 7.5V in my case with an integrator ?

Comment: An integrator integrates, a low pass filter produces a mean value with some ripple. Choose the low pass filter cut-off frequency to reduce ripple to an acceptable level. Use a simple low pass filter using the 10 k resistor and 100 uF capacitor if you wish.

Comment: @c.leblanc  If you want to turn your current structure into a low pass, simply add a resistor in parallel to your capacitor and play around with the values to get what you want.  However, it will still invert your signal.  If you want to not invert, you can do what Andy is suggesting and do something like this:  https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/fil20a.gif

Comment: I thought by integrating I would get a constant value representing the area of the signal so a relation expressing the ratio between the "amount of time" it is at 15v and the "amount of time" it is at 0V (I made it more simple here but in my actual circuit those times aren't necessarily the same). I guess I'm seeing it wrong ^^

Comment: An integrator integrates; it doesn't average anything. Your advisor is incorrect. A low pass filter averages (as I previously advised). @c.leblanc

Comment: Ok, tbh it's probably us who didn't link what he was talking about with the right thing, we're at the start of a project with a lot of different components and a lot of new information. Thanks for the advice, I'll try those things out!

Comment: @c.leblanc  Your integrator will keep adding areas "under the curve" but nothing will "reset" it to tell it start over again at the beginning of each cycle of the square wave.  So it will keep adding and adding and adding until it saturates at the rail of the opamp and get stuck there.

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem with your advice. Now what if I would use a square signal with a positive and negative part (e.g. -15v to 15v), would an integrator give me in that case something around 0V if both negative and positive part are equal and around more or less than 0V if they aren't equal?

Comment: The integrator would produce precisely 0 volts with a truly bipolar square wave but, reality is that it would slowly head off and hit one of the power rails after some time due to offset errors in the op-amp. If the op-amp were perfect (ideal) and the square wave was 99.999999 % bipolar, the op-amp output would still head off on a slow walk until the output hit one of the the power rails @c.leblanc